# How does one write an equation with cases properly?

Tags: cases

Why doesn't this display properly:

```
\begin{equation}
steps(x^{(i)}) = 
    \begin{cases} 
        1                                                    & \mbox{ if } x^{(i)}.g = leaf \\
        1 + \sum_{g \in children(x) } steps(proof\_state(g)) & \mbox{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

I want it to be an equation with cases. It says

```
misplaced alignment tab character &
```

but according to other examples it looks fine to me.

Comment: Did you add `\usepackage{amsmath}`?

Comment: @egreg how did you know that was needed?

Comment: Because the `cases` environment is defined by that package.

Comment: @CharlieParker The code is good according to the `cases` environment as defined by `amsmath`. However, for historical reasons, there is a `\cases` command in the LaTeX kernel, derived from `plain.tex`, that has a different syntax (and should be avoided).

Answer (score 1):

This was solved once

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

was added at the top.

Comment: alternatively, you can load the 'mathtool' package (it loads amsmath, as well)

Answer (score 1):

I propose 3 alternatives:

---

**First option**:

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\textup{steps}(x^{(i)}) = 
    \begin{cases} 
        1   & \textup{if } x^{(i)}.g = \textup{leaf}\\
        &\\
        1 + \displaystyle\sum_{g \in \textup{children(x)}} \textup{steps}(\textup{proof}\_\textup{state}(g)) & \textup{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Second option:**

---

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    
    \begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    \textup{steps}(x^{(i)}) = 
        \begin{cases} 
            1   & \textup{if } x^{(i)}.g = \textup{leaf}\\
            1 + \displaystyle\sum_{g \in \textup{children(x)}} \textup{steps}(\textup{proof}\_\textup{state}(g)) & \textup{otherwise}
        \end{cases}
    \end{equation}
    \end{document}

[![enter image description here][2]][2]
```

---

**Third option:**

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2-3]
\begin{equation}
\textup{steps}(x^{(i)}) = 
    \begin{cases} 
        1   & \textup{if } x^{(i)}.g = \textup{leaf}\\
        &\\
        1 + \displaystyle\sum_{g \in \textup{children(x)}} \textup{steps}(\textup{proof}\_\textup{state}(g)) & \textup{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like the first one. Btw, how do I make sure it doesn't go out of the margins? Document looks unprofessional otherwise :(

Comment: You can add geometry package setting the desidered margins. https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf

Comment: @CharlieParker You can see the last code. Your formula doesn't go out of the margins.

Answer (score 1):

I propose two variants, based on the `empheq` package, which loads `mathtools`, hence `amsmath`. In the second variant, both equations are numbered:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left={\text{steps}\bigl(x^{(i)}\bigr) =} \empheqlbrace]{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
        & 1 && \text{if } x^{(i)}.g = \text{leaf}\\
         & 1 + \smashoperator{\sum_{g \in \text{children(x)}}} \text{steps}(\text{proof}\_\text{state}(g)) &\quad & \textup{otherwise}
\end{alignedat}
\end{empheq}
\bigskip
\begin{empheq}[left={\text{steps}\bigl(x^{(i)}\bigr) =} \empheqlbrace]{alignat=2}
        & 1 && \text{if } x^{(i)}.g = \text{leaf}\\
         & 1 + \smashoperator{\sum_{g \in \text{children(x)}}} \text{steps}(\text{proof}\_\text{state}(g)) &\quad & \textup{otherwise}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for a lot of effort.

Comment: Thanks, @Sebastiano. The only effort was to think of the tools to improve the layout ;o)